# how to add symbols to text at flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the way to write these symbols in Flutter (the symbols directed by the red arrow on image)?
[image]

Comment: Why you can't use ```Icon()``` widget?

Comment: what do you mean how to write them? you have them written right there

Comment: @IvoBeckers I Found this code , and wanna to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **VS code** or **Android Studio** press `Window + .`  open emoji window choose your emoji from list.

[image]

Result Screen-> [image]

Or you can put [**`unicode`**](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt) charecter

```
Text('\u274C '),
```

Result Screen-> [image]